# Finding the matrix for a projection map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have been given the two vectors: $a_1 = (1,0,1,0,0)^T, a_2 = (0,1,0,1,0)^T$, they are elements of the $\mathbb R^5$ vector space. Now let $U_1$ be the subspace formed by the span of those two vectors.

I found a complementary subspace $U_2=span(a_3,a_4,a_5)$,whereas $a_3 = (0,0,0,0,1)^T, a_4=(0,0,0,1,0)^T, a_5 = (1,0,0,0,0)^T$ (at least I think that is the right answer, correct me if I am wrong).

Now I would like to find the matrices $\langle E^*,p_1(E)\rangle,\langle E^*,p_2(E)\rangle $. $E$ stands for the canonical basis, and $p_1$ is the projection map which maps a vector $x$ to its component of $U_1$ and $p_2$ maps a vector to its $U_2$ component.

How do I find the matrices of these linear maps?

Comment: Note that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are orthogonal.  So the projection onto $U_1$ will be the sum of the projections onto $\operatorname{span}(a_1)$ and $\operatorname{span}(a_2)$.  Then once you have the projection matrix onto $U_1$ use what you know about decomposing a vector into its components wrt its projection onto a subspace and its orthogonal complement to get the projection matrix onto $U_2$.

Comment: Bye_World basically gave the hint to the answer. Also note that while $a_3$ is orthogonal to $U_1$, $a_4$ and $a_5$ isn't. Perhaps you could use instead $a_4=(1/\sqrt{2},0,-1/\sqrt{2},0,0)^T$ and $a_5=(0,1/\sqrt{2},0,-1/\sqrt{2},0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $V$ such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$ and $A+ B = V$.  Then any $v\in V$ can be uniquely decomposed as $v = a + b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

**Hint 2:** Similarly let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be disjoint subsets of $V$ such that $A + B + C = V$.  Then any $v\in V$ can be uniquely decomposed as $v = a + b + c$ where $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $c\in C$.

**Hint 3:** (Adding on to Hint 1) If $B=A^\perp$ then $a = \operatorname{proj}_A(v)$ and $b = \operatorname{proj}_B(v)$.

**Hint 4:** The projection matrix onto the space spanned by a vector $v$ is $$P_v= \frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$$

---

**Solution:**

General idea:

> From the above and the fact that $U_{11} = \operatorname{span}(a_1)$, $U_{12} = \operatorname{span}(a_2)$, and $U_2$ are mutually orthogonal subspaces whose sum is the entire vector space $\Bbb R^5$, we know that for any $v\in \Bbb R^5$, $$v = \operatorname{proj}_{U_{11}}(v) + \operatorname{proj}_{U_{12}}(v) + \operatorname{proj}_{U_2}(v)$$  Put another way $I = P_{U_1} + P_{U_2}$, where $P_{U_1} = P_{U_{11}} + P_{U_{12}}$.

So first we find the projection matrices onto $\operatorname{span}(a_1)$ and $\operatorname{span}(a_2)$.

> Using the formula above we have $$P_{U_{11}} = \frac{a_1a_1^T}{a_1^Ta_1} = \frac 12\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0} \\ P_{U_{12}} = \frac{a_2a_2^T}{a_2^Ta_2} = \frac 12\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$$

Then we can use that to find the projection onto $U_2$:

> Knowing that $I = P_{U_{11}} + P_{U_{12}} + P_{U_2}$, we can just rearrange to get $$P_{U_2} = I - P_{U_{11}} - P_{U_{12}} = \frac 12\pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I do understand most of that. But practically: Lets say I want to map $E_1$ or $(1,0,0,0,0)^T$ onto $U_1$. Then I would get $E_1 = 0*a_1+0*a_2$ right?

Comment: ^^ Yes, that was what I was asking. Am I right then if I say that the matrix $\langle E^*,p_1(E)\rangle$ only consists of zeroes? Because it's the same for every vector of the canonical basis in this case?

Comment: @M3xr I've added the solution in case you still need assistance.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I am slowly starting to understand the exercise now!

Comment: Just on a side note: Could I theoretically solve this without using the formula by saying: I want to find a matrix different from the identity matrix that, if I multiply it with $a_1$ (in the other case $a_2$) I will get $a_1$ again - that way I can just write out the equations and choose values that fit?

Comment: There are infinitely many different matrices which fix $a_1$.  If you want to specify the matrix by its action on a basis, then you're going to need to extend the set $\{a_1, a_2\}$ to an orthonormal basis $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}$.  Then $P_{U_{11}}$ will be the matrix such that $a_1\mapsto a_1$ and $a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5 \mapsto 0$.  Likewise for the other projection matrices.

Comment: I see, thanks!!